# Determine the characteristic of orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u,v,w$ be three points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not lying in any plane containing the origin then,

1. u,v,w are mutually orthogonal
2. one of u,v,w has to be zero
3. u,v,w cannot be pairwise orthogonal
4. $\alpha_1 u+\alpha_2 v+\alpha_3 w=0 ~\text{implies}~ \alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=0$

Which is/are true??

my opinion option 2 is not right because these three points not lying in the plane containg origin.
Mutually orthogonal and paiwise orthogonal both are same??
I have no idea about option 4.
Can any one please help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 4 is **true**. The condition $\alpha_1 u + \alpha_2 v + \alpha_3 w = 0 \implies \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = 0$ is precisely the definition of linear independence of the list $(u, v, w)$. As your notes should show, three vectors that are *not* linearly independent should be contained in a plane containing the origin.

Let's prove it. Suppose that $(u, v, w)$ are not contained in any plane containing the origin. In other words, we do not have $u, v, w \in \operatorname{span}(x, y)$ for any $x, y$. Further, suppose that
$$\alpha_1 u + \alpha_2 v + \alpha_3 w = 0$$
for some scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$. We wish to show that these scalars are $0$.

Consider first that
$$\alpha_1 u = (-\alpha_2)v + (-\alpha_3)w.$$
If $\alpha_1 \neq 0$, then we may divide both sides by $\alpha_1$, to get $u$ as a linear combination of $v$ and $w$. Therefore, $u, v, w \in \operatorname{span}(v, w)$, a plane through the origin.

A similar argument works for $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$. Thus, $(u, v, w)$ are linearly independent, and point 4 holds.